# How to merge into branch without commit?

Tags: git

Let's say I have `branch1` and I created a new `branch2` off of it. I commit twice to `branch2`. How do I mege branch2 back down to `branch1` without any evidence of `branch2` existing?

Diagram:

Initial state:

```
                  E---F  branch2
             /
A---B---C---D  branch1
```

Wanted state:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F  branch1
```

But instead I get something like this:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F---(M)  branch1 with extra Merge Commit
```

Note: I'm using Intellij IDEA to do my git commands.

Comment: remove your `branch1` and rename `branch2` to `branch1`

Comment: Command-line Git does what you want by default. Apparently your GUI overrides the command line, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3):

> In git branches are only pointers to commit

In your case you just need to do:

```
git checkout branch1
git merge branch2
```

It will merge without any merge commit (optimization by git) if you have not commited anything new to branch1.

In normal scenario git should always create a merge commit. But in this peculiar case where parent branch has not done any commit since creation of child branch it just update reference.

```
              E---F  branch2
             /
A---B---C---D  branch1
```

After merging:

```
              E---F  branch1/branch2
             /
A---B---C---D
```

Incase here you want to have a merge commit so merge with --no-ff option.

```
git checkout branch1
git merge --no-ff branch2
```

In case you had a new commit after creation of new branch, merge commit creation is inevitable. Say example:

```
               E---F  branch2
             /
A---B---C---D ----G  branch1
```

So now merge commit is only rescuer here:

```
              E--------F  branch2
             /         \
A---B---C---D ----G-----H(merge commit)  
                          branch1
```

In above case a new merge commit is formed and branch1 is updated with its reference.

Comment: from branch1 (at G): `git cherry-pick E F`

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you could simply reset branch1 to what branch2 is currently pointing, and then delete branch2:

```
git checkout branch1 -B branch2
git branch -D branch2
```

The more general answer would be to rebase branch2 on top of branch1 first (which in your case would not change anything, since branch1 has no commit done after branch2 branch)